# Is proc toolbar a hidden procedure?

Tags: sas

I got it by chance.
Submit this to SAS:

```
proc toolbar;
quit;
```

The Log says:`ERROR: Unable to open ...`, I think it indicates `proc toolbar` is some kind of procedure but I just didn't use correct syntax. Because if there is not a procedure named `toolbar` it would be another kind of hint: `ERROR: PROCEDURE XXX not find`. You can validate it using the following example.

```
proc XXX;
quit;
```

I dont't find any documents about `proc toolbar`. How do you know about it? could you please share with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, custom toolbars for SAS display manager sessions are created using the display manager command `TOOLDEF` and loaded (or attached) to a window using command `TOOLLOAD`.

`Proc TOOLBAR` may be a deprecated or an abandoned experimental procedure that is for programmatically creating custom toolbars.

As for

```
ERROR: Unable to open ...
```

The mystery of what `...` *is* remains.

Attempts to specify a procedure option produces a log message

```
ERROR 22-322: Expecting ;.
```

So maybe the procedure does not allow options.

The procedure does process an `ITEM` statement that was likely the syntax for associating an entry with a command and icon

```
item <name> command="<command>" icon=<icon-number>
```

Every attempt to run `Proc TOOLBAR` will create a new temporary catalog in the `WORK` folder.

```
proc toolbar cat=work.play.one;
  item work command="dir work" icon="123";
  item view command='viewtable &syslast';
quit;
```

*Aside for icons*

The SAS display manager command `regedit` raises the SAS registry editor window.  Icon numbers for various classifier mnemonic can be seen in the drill path `SAS_REGISTRY/CORE/CLASSIFIERS` and for SAS explorer at `SAS_REGISTRY/CORE/EXPLORER/ICONS`. The SAS registry editor does not display the icon image that corresponds to the icon number.

Example:

Classifier 100 is named COPYITEM and will show icon #173 in the display manager UI. The datatype of the names are strings as shown by the preceding `[ab]` icon.

[image]

However, you can download and run an improved registry viewer application built with SAS/AF that **does** show icon images adjacent to icon numbers.

[image]

See page ["SAS/AF Registry Browser"](https://www.devenezia.com/downloads/sas/af/index.php?topic=12) for information about the viewer application.  The viewer can be installed and run by submitting

```
LIBNAME EXAMPLE "%sysfunc(pathname(WORK))";

filename INSTALL
 URL "https://www.devenezia.com:443/downloads/sas/af/example/registry-browser/registry-browser.xpt"
;

PROC CIMPORT LIB=EXAMPLE FILE=INSTALL;
RUN;

filename INSTALL;

proc display cat=EXAMPLE.REGISTRY.BROWSER.FRAME;
run;
```

Other interesting artifacts from bygone days

- `Proc PMENU`
- [SAS Explorer use and customization](https://www.devenezia.com/papers/nesug-2005/AP006.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of procs in SAS that are dead/defunct. They are normally very hard to find info on. A few years ago, with some sleuthing, I got proc explode to work. An old procedure to write large letters on greenbar back in the mainframe printer days. I am sure there are many, many more. I think I remember proc toolbar but has been 20+ years. Maybe an AF proc when SAS was on the old editor.

Honestly, I would ignore it as having any value. I suspect dozens of abandoned procs in the code base.

Comment: Here is a fun thread ending with proc spell, another defunct piece of code: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/PROC-EXPLODE-The-SAS-procedure-that-time-forgot/ta-p/473102